# Create VIEW with IF STATEMENT (WEEKDAY CASE)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a view in SQL Server which returns different results, from a different table, for each day of the week.

It is possible to create a view like below?.

For example, If it's Sunday, it returns rows from `Tbl_FRUITS` and if it's Monday, it returns rows from `Tbl_VEGETABLE`.

```
CREATE VIEW TBL_CART
AS
IF (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = '1')
    SELECT * FROM Tbl_FRUITS
ELSE IF (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = '2')
    SELECT * FROM Tbl_VEGETABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all` with your condition as the appropriate `where` clause. You will need to ensure you return the same columns from each different table - but that normal for a view anyway. Repeat the unions for as many days as you have different tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM Tbl_FRUITS
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Tbl_VEGETABLE
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 2;
```

Note: As mentioned by Gordon Linoff, you don't quote numbers (that makes them strings). And you don't compare numbers to string.

Comment: I Interfaces with other system with one VIEW.
If I have to return different data for each day, should I use Union ALL 7 times?

Comment: You should not be comparing an integer to a string value.